# Get constants information of facebook user

Tags: android, facebook

On my Graph API request /me I get much data about user. But not see contacts information: phone, address, skype, yahoo...
But in native andoid application [facebook](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.facebook.katana&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5mYWNlYm9vay5rYXRhbmEiXQ..) this data present.
Can I get this information also?

Answer (score 0):

This data is reliant of the privacy settings of the user you are requesting information about. You may need to request additional permissions to get/obtain this data: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ has some details on additional permissions.

Getting your own data should return most information as you are authenticated as you.
What you might find is you are putting in a request to /me and you haven't authenticated, where as in the Android App you haven't realised you have.